# Addressing progressbar inside an itemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

i have the following code:

```
<mx:Script>
    //I WANT TO ADRESS THE FUNCTION INSIDE MY HBOX FROM HERE
</mx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg_uploads" x="10" y="10" width="500" height="350" editable="false" variableRowHeight="true">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="progress" sortable="true" paddingLeft="10">
                <mx:itemRenderer>

                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:HBox>
                            <mx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                public function updateProgress(event:CustomEvent):void {
                                    trace(event);
                                    bar.setProgress( event.data.bytesLoaded, event.data.bytesTotal );
                               }
                               ]]>
                            </mx:Script>
                            <mx:VBox>
                                <mx:ProgressBar id="bar" labelPlacement="top" minimum="0" visible="true" maximum="100" verticalGap="0"
                                                color="0x323232" label="{data.name}" direction="right" mode="manual" fontWeight="bold" trackHeight="10" width="280" bottom="0"/>
                                <mx:ProgressBar id="subbar" mode="manual" direction="right" labelPlacement="bottom" minimum="0" visible="true" label="{data.status}"
                                                maximum="100" width="280" styleName="subBarStyle"/>
                            </mx:VBox>
                            <mx:Image source="images/Clear-Red-Button.png" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" click="outerDocument.deleteItem(event)" />
                            <mx:Image source="images/Clear-Green-Button.png" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" click="outerDocument.stopUploadProcess(event)" />
                        </mx:HBox>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>          
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>   
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

How can i adress the function inside the hbox script from outside the hbox script? I want to trigger it when the document starts

Comment: The script tag must be inside your ItemRenderer

Comment: I moved the script tag inside the itemRenderer but it still cant be found

Comment: The actual ItemRenderer is the Component tag. The `itemRenderer` tag only represents the DataGridColumn#itemRenderer property. Try moving the script block inside the Component tag.

Comment: Now i get the following error: parse error at '<mx:Script>'

Comment: Sorry, my Flex 3 is a little rusty: try moving it down one level, into the HBox.

Comment: Yep this is working. I got 1 more question, because i have other code inside my script tag i added a second 1 but i cant adress it, i updated my post to explain my problem a bit further.

Comment: That's not possible. You have to realize that if there are 10 items in the grid, there are 10 ItemRenderers and 10 functions called `updateProgress`. Which one would you be calling? Perhaps you'd better explain what it is that you're trying to achieve. I mean functionally.

Comment: well i'm uploading documents, and from the urlLoaders progressEvent, im dispatching an event. So i want to update the progressbar inside the datarow with the correct {data.name}.

Comment: Alright so the best way to go about doing this is to add a bindable property inside the data itself that you modify rather than trying to access the individual item renderer instances directly.  Whatever your dataprovider is for the data grid has some collection of objects, those objects have properties, add one that is bindable that you then bind the progress to, on the progress event iterate over the items in the dg's dp and update the appropriate variable, the view being bound to it (the item renderer) will update automatically.

Comment: Also I strongly suggest defining your item renderers in a separate MXML file as to avoid the confusion and to keep the code cleaner, there isn't a single instance of this in the view, this is a template for a ClassFactory to generate itemRenderer instances as needed, it's slightly clearer to think of it that way when it's in a separate file.